# Magento admin category page fails on PHP 5.4

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I have a Magento 1.6.2 site hosted on 1&1.  Because of certain installed extensions I must have support for PHP version 5.3, but sadly the available options with 1&1 are PHP 5.2 or something they call PHP Dev.  A quick `phpinfo()` shows that this is in fact PHP 5.4.

My problem is that when I'm set to 5.4, the Categories page of the backend throws a 500 error.  Rolling back to 5.2 fixes the issue, but that breaks my product pages.  In the short term I can handle having to swap between them, but this is obviously unacceptable for a long-term solution when the site is handed to the client.

Can anyone suggest where this incompatibility might lie, and what steps I might take to fix it?  My biggest impediment is that the hosting is on a shared server, and so I am not allowed to look at the Apache logs.

**Update:**

As per CCBlackburn's suggestion in the comments, I have tried to track the point that the error originates from, but I have to admit that I don't really understand the results I'm getting.  The URL of the categories page looks like this:

`example.com/index.php/admin/catalog_category/index/key/blahblah`

I presumed that `Mage_Adminhtml_CatalogController` would be the place to start looking, but a `Mage::log()` call as the first line in `indexAction()` failed to write to the log.

I decided to move up the inheritance and  cut into the constructor, and so added the following to `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`:

```
function __construct(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract $response, array $invokeArgs = array()) {
    Mage::log('construct pre');
    parent::__construct($request,$response,$invokeArgs);
    Mage::log('construct post');
}
```

This was better, as the first log call wrote to the file, but the second did not.

Next I moved up the inheritance again, and modified the constructor of `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` as follows:

```
public function __construct(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract $response, array $invokeArgs = array())
{
    Mage::log('request: '.$request);
    $this->_request = $request;
    Mage::log('response: '.$response);
    $this->_response= $response;
    Mage::log('pre set action');
    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->setAction($this);
    Mage::log('post set action');
    $this->_construct();
}
```

The problem is that none of these log calls do anything.  This has me stumped, as surely calling `parent::__construct();` from `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` should execute at least one more log call before it does anything.  Unless the issue exists with the incoming values, but I don't know how I can check/debug that?

Comment: Are there any errors showing in the Magento logs - system.log or exception.log?

Comment: None at all.  Before I realised that it was the fault of 5.4 I had reinstalled the site from scratch, and the log files never even generated.  I'm sure the Apache log would tell the tale, if only I was allowed to look at it.

Comment: Darn, the only thing I can think is to put Mage::Log calls in, so you can see where it falls over

Comment: contact hosting and let them send you the logs

Comment: @Anton - I tried that, got a canned response about using some custom error handling code which didn't work.

Comment: didn't try enough :) hosting where you can't access all logs is not a hosting

Comment: @CCBlackburn - I've tried, and the results have got me stumped!

Comment: I just added the same piece of logging to the `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` construct and received this error `Object of class Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http could not be converted to string`...maybe just try `Mage::log($request);` instead?

Comment: Ah yes, that would make sense.  Tiredness is the mind killer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same problem under OSX Lion in Google Chrome and Apple Safari with Magento 1.7 and PHP 5.4. Suddenly Magento Category admin started giving 500 Errors and I had no clue what was happening. It seems it's a problem with PHP 5.4. At first I thought it was XDebug causing this error. Then I disabled XDebug and the problem was still there. It is weirder than weird that it works with Firefox!

My solution was to downgrade to the latest PHP 5.3, however this has now been **fixed as of PHP 5.4.3**.